# Can we approximate any eigenvalue of an infinite matrix via eigenvalues of some sequence of submatrices which approximates the matrix?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues, approximation-theory

Let $T:\ell^2\to\ell^2$ be a compact linear operator. Let $[T]=(a_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^{\infty}$ be the representing infinite matrix of $T$ with respect to the canonical base. Let $T_n$ be the finite rank operator defined by the matrix $(a_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^{n}$ embedded into an infinite matrix. Thus $T_n\to T$ in norm.

Can we approximate the eigenvalues of $T$ with eigenvalues of $T_n$? or more specifically, given $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $T$, is there a sequence $(\lambda_n)$ such that $\lambda_n$ is an eigenvalue of $T_n$ and $\lambda_n\to\lambda$?  Any recommended reference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szeg%C5%91_limit_theorems

Comment: @SteveHuntsman: The relevance of this link to the question isn't clear to me, can you please elaborate.

Comment: For Toeplitz matrices the Szego theorems show how the spectrum converges to what electrical engineers call the transfer function of the corresponding filter.

Comment: Your last sentence is unclear to me.  Do you mean to ask "do the eigenvalues of $T_n$ necessarily approximate those of $T$ in some sense?"  or "is it possible that the eigenvalues of $T_n$ approximate $T$ (in some sense)?" or something else?

Comment: In any case, perhaps you are looking for something like [this](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611970678).

Comment: @DavidKetcheson: I have edited the question and I hope it is clear now. Thanks for the reference, I will look into it.

Comment: Might be a good idea to also tag this with `numerical-analysis`